# Add feature to log in using your username

Tags: feature-request, login

Would we it be possible to add the ability to login using your username or you email, because many people nowadays, including myself, have many email addresses and it's difficult to keep track of which email address I have used with each site.

Is this something that can be implemented to SO or not?

Comment: With over 6.6m users on stack overflow alone according to http://stackexchange.com/sites it would be very tricky  to create a unique username to allow logins.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usernames are not unique, so you can't use them as credentials when logging in.

Comment: oh, Thanks, never actually realised that usernames werent unique, i just assumed they were like with 99% of other sites